# Unity not finding IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessObserver

Tags: c#, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

I am using the Microsoft MRTK v2.0.3, and I'm trying to add spatial awareness to my project, but when I select a spatial awareness profile I keep getting the following error:

```
Unable to register IMixedRealitySpatialAwarenessObserver service with a null concrete type.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.BaseDataProviderAccessCoreSystem:RegisterDataProviderInternal(Boolean, Type, SupportedPlatforms, Object[]) (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/BaseDataProviderAccessCoreSystem.cs:178)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.BaseDataProviderAccessCoreSystem:RegisterDataProvider(Type, SupportedPlatforms, Object[]) (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/BaseDataProviderAccessCoreSystem.cs:151)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SpatialAwareness.MixedRealitySpatialAwarenessSystem:InitializeInternal() (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Services/SpatialAwarenessSystem/MixedRealitySpatialAwarenessSystem.cs:96)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.SpatialAwareness.MixedRealitySpatialAwarenessSystem:Initialize() (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit.Services/SpatialAwarenessSystem/MixedRealitySpatialAwarenessSystem.cs:78)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.<>c:<InitializeAllServices>b__60_0(IMixedRealityService) (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:923)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:ExecuteOnAllServicesInOrder(Action`1) (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:1019)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:InitializeAllServices() (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:923)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:InitializeServiceLocator() (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:468)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.MixedRealityToolkit:ResetConfiguration(MixedRealityToolkitConfigurationProfile) (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Services/MixedRealityToolkit.cs:120)
Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Editor.<>c__DisplayClass30_0:<OnInspectorGUI>b__0() (at Assets/MixedRealityToolkit/Inspectors/Profiles/MixedRealityToolkitConfigurationProfileInspector.cs:428)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallDelayFunctions() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorApplication.cs:209)
```

When I try to emulate on device there is no data collected about the surrounding. I have spatial perception and VR support activated.

Comment: The latest release of MRTK is 2.3, this release provides new features and fixes some known bugs. As a test, we recommend that you backup your project first, and then follow this doc upgrade MRTK to the latest version: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/version/releases/2.3.0/Documentation/Updating.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue fixed (an several others of the same kind) by looking through all the Profiles inside the MixedRealityToolkit (GameObject and its script of the same name). Just watch out for red-marked fields that indicate that some component could not be found.

[image]

In this particular case, look inside the "Spatial Awareness"-Group,  make a clone of the existing profile and use **Try Fixing** next to the red input field. In case this is not working, search for the *WindowsMixedRealitySpatialMeshObserver* by hand.

I hope this helps you too.